# Nginx: How to set default server for same port but different server name

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to serve 2 servers from one IP with 2 different server names but same port.

> name.one.com:443 --> 192.168.10.1:80
>
> name.two.com:443 --> 192.168.10.2:80

**Question**

How do I set different **default server**s for `name.one.com` and `name.two.com` in `Nginx`?

**My research**

The [document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) says:

> Note that the default server is a property of the listen port and not of the server name.

I understand this as "you can only set different default servers for different ports, regardless of server names".

So I think `default_server` directive won't work.

I'm thinking of not using `default_server` directive at all and try to set the server names with appropriate regex so that for each server names with no matches, they will be routed to the *pseudo default* servers.

Comment: The first part of your question seems to be asking something from the last paragraph. You have answer the first part  `Note that the default server is a property of the listen port and not of the server name.` As you have read you can't set a default for different names. Are you instead trying to handle requests for everything other than name.one.com and name.two.com?

Comment: Have a look at [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html). The `default_server` is only used when the server name is not recognised.

Comment: What I want is to have this kind of reverse proxy in place:

 name.one.com/undefinedlocation -> default-server-one AND 

name.two.com/undefinedlocation -> default-server-two

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding what `default_server` does, from the docs.... the default server is the first one — which is nginx’s standard default behaviour. It can also be set explicitly which server should be default, with the default_server parameter. It isn't about handling the default server the requests are proxied to

Comment: You just make a `server` block for each name and `proxy_pass` to wherever you want. This is such a common setup that you've probably done it many times before already.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that "listen port" can include an IP address part.

Hence this should work for you:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.10.1:80 default_server;
    server_name name.one.com;
    # here the rest of your server config
}

server {
    listen 192.168.10.2:80 default_server;
    server_name name.two.com;
    # here the rest of your server config
}
```

Requests are handled by trying to match the `Host:` header to a `server_name` configuration item in a `server` stanza. Only if no match is found will the `default_server` server stanza be used.

So, requests coming in to 192.168.10.1:80 will be handled by the `default_server` stanza if not matched by any other `server_name` stanza, same for 192.168.10.2:80.

Comment: This listens to TWO different IPs. In my case, I am using only one IP.

Comment: Then you can only have one default server. Think about what a "default" server means...

Comment: @TranTriet: You may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14434262/6381711) out as well. As rightly pointed by @wurtel, `default_server` goes with the true meaning of the word *default*.